# Is it possible to format a string in different ways in MVC Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my form I have a collection of fields which are output via an editor template.

```
Form.cs
IList<Field> MyFields {get;set;}

Field.cs
string Name {get;set;}
string DisplayFormat {get;set;}
string Value {get;set;}
```

The complication here is that the value field can be of a different type amongst the fields. Some are numeric, and some are text. For the numeric fields, I am trying to format them in a particular way - i.e. 1111 for a particular field should format to 1,111 and so on. This is quite easy to implement when I set the value property to a decimal, but I can't then use this model across different types of fields. I've tried a few variations of:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Value, Model.DisplayFormat, htmlAttributes)
```

but I cannot seem to get the format to be applied. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?
Example editor template below:

For a bit more background:
My project is basically a collection of forms with all of the 'metadata' for the fields on that form stored in XML. So each form is made up of multiple fields and each field has a particular display format. Some of the fields are numeric, and should be displayed in a certain way - as stated 1,111 for 1111 or 11,111,11 for 1111111. Some of the fields have text in them.

At the moment - I create the field objects from the metadata, populate it with values from the database and pass them to my editor template, where users can update the fields.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example so others can at least duplicate your problem. `Model` is a `Field`? Show us some values (with corresponding format) you attempting and what do you get?

Comment: What are you setting your DisplayFormat value to in your model? Also, decimal place formatting will not work on a string like that - you'd have to convert the value to decimal first, then apply your formatting. Using
`Convert.ToDecimal("1111").ToString("N0")` will give you `1,111`.

Comment: In case of your structure it might be better to already set Value's value to a formatted string, before sending Model to view. Where do you have original value which you format (before you convert it to string)?

Comment: The value is stored in a database. The value is edited in the view, so if I display a formatted value, then I'd need to translate it back presumably?

Comment: I've added some more background Jansen, hopefully this helps. The Field.cs class is a model. I've purposely scaled it down - as the only property I am interested in is the Value property. This is currently a string, but I would like to display it in different formats - my example was 1111 as 1,111.

Comment: Thanks - X3074861X. I am setting the format as you suggest, but also as in your example, I can only get this working on a numeric type, where I need to keep it as a string.

Comment: You can't format a `string` (only numeric and DateTime properties). In the controller, use `decimal.TryParse()` to convert the value. If it succeeds, do your formatting and update the property value before you send it to the view. If not, leave it as it is.